# ag-grid prevent expanding grouped data

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag grid enterprise with grouping.

Is it possible to group data but based on first column but prevent expanding the row? I just want to display the sums.

I am using this data : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/sample-data/rowData.json

Please check the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-varahamihira-1r8bf?file=/src/App.js

[image: image to show how it renderes in UI]

As you can see in the image, I just want to display the total sum of prices of Toyota, Ford etc, but I do not want the users to expand them.

Comment: why don't you enable pivot mode? in that mode only the grouped column and aggregated columns are visible in grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the children, why you need a tree view for it?
You should do this logic in component and only pass the sums data to the grid.

Comment: In my production application I have 5 levels of data, I want to take advantage of grouping to show aggregated data up to 3 levels. Let me know if it makes sense.